# Fixed header in Hub control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How do I turn off header movement in the Hub control in Windows Phone 8.1?
Like in the "MixRadio" app.

I tried to find a property setting like this, but I was unsuccessful.

```
    <Hub x:Name="HubControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="640" Background="Black">
        <Hub.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold">
                        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="An"/>
                        <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="App"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="updating mix..."/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Hub.Header>
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="1 page"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="2 page"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

Second question: how do I remove the space between the first and second header text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Pull the header out of the Hub and it will be static.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold">
            <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="An"/>
            <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="App"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="updating mix..."/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Hub x:Name="HubControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black"
            Grid.Row="1">
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="1 page"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,18,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="2 page"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

2.Remove the Margin (or even set a negative value to make it even closer)

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold">
        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="An"/>
        <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="App"/>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,-4,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="updating mix..."/>
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT 1:

For the second part, you can just use two TextBlocks instead of Runs.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" Text="An" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Normal" Text="App" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,-4,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Text="updating mix..."/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have asked about first and second text with content: "An" & "App". There is a space between those texts. Can you check it? 
I will be grateful for the assistance. :)

Comment: Thank you for your support! Please, can you tell me, where I can take more information about WP8.1 development except of MSDN? For example, I want mooore info about Hub control for WP. Before I have not seen before words about Runs :(